# Link re-interpreted by browser does not work

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting, dynamic

I have a problem with links generated by php, for example this link works:

`http://masterarbeit-im-unternehmen.de/Thema_Analyse-und-Darstellung-der-%C3%B6kologischen-Vorteile-des-Remanufacturings-f%C3%BCr-die-Corporate-Responsibility-Strategie-und-Marketing-anhand-eines-Beispielprodukts-3966.html`

but when that is opened in the browser it is turned into this link:

`/Thema_Analyse%20und%20Darstellung%20der%20%C3%B6kologischen%20Vorteile%20des%0ARemanufacturings%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20Corporate%20Responsibility%20Strategie%20und%20Marketing%20anhand%20eines%0ABeispielprodukts-3966.html`

Now, I have sent this link to other people but it does not open the page I want it to show. So my question are:

1. Why is the browser doing this re-interpretation of the url?
2. I try to catch the URL that is not working with .htaccess but I can't catch (but I can catch the url that is working) - what is happening?

Comment: Characters in links will be encoded by the browser when sent to the web server. If you have encoding in your link already, that encoding will be encoded with the risk of making the link invalid. Remove the encoding from your original link and you should be fine. Make sure to use valid characters in your links.

Comment: hi, thanks, does that explain why i cannot catch the wrong link with htaccess as well? because it is fundamentally not a link? 

for example this link "/Thema_Analyse%20und%20Darstellung%20der%20%C3%B6kologischen%20Vorteile%20des%0ARemanufacturings%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20Corporate%20Responsibility%20Strategie%20und%20Marketing%20anhand%20eines%0ABeispielprodukts-3966.html" I just cannot grab with htaccess

Comment: I would start by fixing the link. Once you have it working as you expect, edit into your question any .htaccess rules you have so that we can figure that out too. If your .htaccess rules are trying to fix your problem, then you can simply delete it or comment it out.

Comment: @closetnoc But the link already looks "fixed" to me? And the above _link_ works (as stated). "Remove the encoding from your original link" - why? I assume you mean "percent encoding"? At first I thought this might be a character-set encoding issue, but I can't see the problem looking at the string(URL) in a hex editor. The browser appears to be converting the hyphens (`%2D`) in the URL-path into spaces (`%20`), yet the hyphens are perfectly valid in the URL-path unencoded. (?)

Comment: @stnBnu You shouldn't have to resort to .htaccess for this. But just to note that mod_rewrite matches against the **%-decoded** string, if that is what's causing the match to fail?

Comment: The browser is not changing the URL, a script on your site is doing that. If you disable javascript and load your page, the URL does not change. Hopefully that will at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: @w3d I do not encode any links. I let the browser do that. But then again, I do not use special characters (or anything close). He gave us a copy of his link with encoding. My experience is that you just create the link and let the browser worry about encoding. Perhaps I was assuming too much meaning that is how he put his link on his site- it looked like there was double-encoding going on at first brush. I am glad to see you and Tim have a handle on this! I have been in and out this morning so I am not as focused as usual. Doing business before a holiday weekend. Cheers!!

Comment: @w3d A second quick look and I can see that there is no double-encoding. My apologies to the OP!! I had gone cross-eyed. Perhaps more coffee??

Comment: @TimFountain thanks for the tip regarding javascript: it looks like all the links that cause the problem have some encoding in them before they are encoded again (the "pure" links are shown in /sitemap.html).
 
http://masterarbeit-im-unternehmen.de/Thema_Konzeption-der-Anforderungen-und-Erstellung-eines-Lastenhefts-f%C3%BCr-die-Konstruktion-und-Auslegung-der-Schwingtischvergr%C3%B6%C3%9Ferung-in-Catia-V5-3999.html

where as those that do work do not have that issue: http://www.masterarbeit-im-unternehmen.de/Thema_Inselbetrieb-dezentraler-Stromversorgungsanlagen-2203.html

Comment: The links aren't being "encoded again", they are being _changed_ (by JS it seems, as Tim pointed out)? Even the link that does "work" is also being _changed_ (but somehow still works?). All but the last hyphen in the URL-path are being _changed_ to spaces. (?) The URLs on the page (in anchors) appear to have spaces, not hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

Starting on line 322 of your `custom.js` file you have this code as part of the carousel render:

```
var u=window.location.pathname;
u=u.substring(0,u.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
u+="Thema_"+encodeURIComponent(tpquestions[curidx].name)+"-"+tpquestions[curidx].id+".html";
if(!X4.config.isuser)
    window.history.replaceState({qid:tpquestions[curidx].id},"",u);
```

The code is not especially clear, but it seems to be building a URL by encoding a "question" string (presumably this 'question' can contain spaces). It's then setting the URL to that (`window.history.replaceState`) if a condition fails. I guess this is what is causing the URL change you're seeing.

Comment: Probably not directly related to this problem, but `encodeURIComponent()` is also the wrong function to use in this instance. It should be `encodeURI()`.